# Practical number algorithm

Tags: time-limit-exceeded, swift, mathematics

I am trying to write a program to find the practical numbers, from an input from \$1\$ to \$n\$.

[Practical numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_number)

My code is running correctly but it is extremely slow when calculating numbers around 50 - it gets stuck at 44.

```
import Foundation

func getInteger() -> Int {
    var firstNum:Int = 0
    while true {
        // get value from user. Using optional input since readLine returns an optional string.
        let input = readLine()
        // ensure string is not nil
        if let unwrappedInput = input {
            if let unwrappedInt = Int(unwrappedInput) {
                firstNum = unwrappedInt
                break
            }
            else { // the input doesn't convert into an int
                print("`\(unwrappedInput)` is not an integer. Please enter an integer")
            }
        }
        else { // did not enter anything
            print("Please enter an integer")
        }
    }

    return firstNum
}
func addOne(signArray: [Int]) -> [Int] { // finds the combinations
    var signArray2 = [Int]()
    for i in 0...signArray.count-1 {
        signArray2.append (signArray[i])
    }

    for i in 0...signArray2.count-1 {
        if signArray2[i] == 1 {
            signArray2[i] = 0
        }
        else {
            signArray2[i] = 1
            break
        }
    }
    return signArray2
}
func signEval (signArray: [Int], divArray: [Int], inNum: Int) -> Bool  {// changes 2nd
  var counts = 0
    for i in 0...divArray.count-1 {
        if signArray[i] == 0 {
counts = divArray[i] + counts        }
        if counts == inNum {
            return true
        }
    }
        return false
}
print("Please enter a number to find the summable numbers up to that number:")
var input2 = getInteger()// if num = 1 print 1 if num = 2 print 1 and 2 else print >2 1, 2
var inNum = 0
var numHalf = 0.0
var numRound = 0.0
var numCheck = false
var numCheck2 = false
var numQuarter = 0.0
var numSixth = 0.0
var divArray:[Int] = []
var theirArray = [Int]()
var signArray = [Int]()// array of 0s and 1s
var summableArray:[Int] = [1,2] // need to check if num is bigger than 2!
for input in 1...input2 {
        numHalf = Double (input) / 2.0
        numRound = round(numHalf)
        if numRound == numHalf {
            numCheck = true }
        if input > 2 && numCheck == false { // odd numbers greater than one are not summable
        }
        else { // these are possible summable nums
            numQuarter = Double (input) / 4.0
            numRound = round(numQuarter)
            if numRound == numQuarter {
                numCheck = true
            }
            else {
                numCheck = false
            }
            numSixth = Double(input) / 6.0
            numRound = round(numSixth)
            if numRound == numSixth {
                numCheck2 = true }
            else { numCheck2 = false}
            if numCheck == true || numCheck2 == true {
        theirArray = []
        divArray = []
        signArray = []
        summableArray = []
for i in 1...input {
    theirArray.append (i)
    }
for i in 1...input { // creates an array of all the diviors of inputted number
    if input%i == 0 {
        divArray.append (i)
    }
}
        for j in 1...divArray.count {//
            signArray.append(0)
        }

for i in 1...input{
let x: Int = Int(pow(Double(2),Double(input-1)))// int 2 to the power of input -1
    var Boolcheck = false

    for q in 1...x-1 { // i to 2^n -1 (sequence to check)
    Boolcheck = (signEval(signArray: signArray, divArray: divArray, inNum: i))// checks
        signArray = addOne(signArray: signArray)// adding the ones to the array
        if Boolcheck == true {
        summableArray.append(i)// creates array of mini summable numbers
        break
    }
        }
   if summableArray.count == input {
      print ("\(input)")
    }
}
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some points in addition to what Roland already said:

You are correct that the `readLine()` returns an optional and you need
to ensure that it is not `nil`. However, `nil` is only returned on an
end-of-file condition, which means that it makes no sense to call
`readLine()` again. You can only terminate the program in that
situation. That is a typical use-case for `guard`:

```
func readInteger() -> Int {
    while true {
        guard let line = readLine() else {
            fatalError("Unexpected end-of-file")
        }
        if let n = Int(line) {
            return n
        }
        print("Please enter an integer")
    }
}
```

---

Now let's have a look at

```
var signArray2 = [Int]()
for i in 0...signArray.count-1 {
    signArray2.append (signArray[i])
}
```

First, this will crash if `signArray` is empty. Better use a half-open
range instead:

```
for i in 0..<signArray.count { ... }
```

or iterate over the indices

```
for i in signArray.indices {
    signArray2.append (signArray[i])
}
```

or just iterate over the elements:

```
for e in signArray {
    signArray2.append(e)
}
```

But *actually,* you are just copying the array:

```
var signArray2  = signArray
```

---

Determination of the divisors should be done in a separate function.
Your code

```
divArray = []
for i in 1...input {
    if input % i == 0 {
        divArray.append (i)
    }
}
```

can be simplified to

```
divArray = (1...input).filter { input % $0 == 0 }
```

There are various ways to make this faster. For example the observation
that with each divisor \$ i \$ of a number \$ n \$, \$ n/i \$ is another
divisor (see for example [Find all divisors of a natural number](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-divisors-natural-number-set-1/)).
That allows to reduce the number of loop iterations to the square-root of the
given number, and could look like this:

```
func divisors(n: Int) -> [Int] {
    var divs = [Int]()
    for i in 1...Int(sqrt(Double(n))) {
        if n % i == 0 {
            divs.append(i)
            if n/i != i {
                divs.append(n/i)
            }
        }
    }
    return divs // or divs.sorted(), if necessary
}
```

---

Your code

```
signArray = []
for j in 1...divArray.count {//
    signArray.append(0)
}
```

creates an array with the same size as `divArray`, but filled with
zeros. That can be simplified to

```
signArray = Array(repeating: 0, count: divArray.count)
```

---

There is no need to use string interpolation when printing an integer
(or any single value),

```
 print ("\(input)")
```

can be simplified to

```
 print(input)
```

---

### Why is your code slow?

There is a logical error in

```
 let x: Int = Int(pow(Double(2),Double(input-1)))// int 2 to the power of input -1
```

because the number of possible combinations of divisors is
just \$ 2 ^ {\text{number of divisors}} \$, which can be computed as

```
 let x = 1 << divArray.count
```

With that change, your program computes all practical numbers
up to 200 in 0.2 seconds, and up to 1,000 in 25 seconds
(on a MacBook, compiled in Release mode, with optimization).

---

### A faster algorithm

In order to determine if \$ n \$ is a practical number,
you test all numbers \$ 1 \le i \le n \$ if they are a sum
of distinct divisors of \$ n \$, and for each \$ i \$ that is done by building all
possible sums of divisors, until \$ i \$ is found.

It is more efficient to work the other way around. From the list of
divisors of  \$ n \$, build a list of all sums of distinct divisors.
This can be done iteratively: Starting with  \$ 0 \$, the first, second, ...
divisor is added to the numbers obtained previously.
Then check if all numbers from \$ 1 ... n-1 \$ are in that list.

The following implementation uses a boolean array to mark all numbers
which are confirmed as sums of divisors. In addition, it uses that
powers of two are always practical numbers (using the method from
[Determining if an integer is a power of 2](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2)).

```
func divisors(_ n: Int) -> [Int] {
    var divs = [Int]()
    for i in 1...Int(sqrt(Double(n))) {
        if n % i == 0 {
            divs.append(i)
            if n/i != i {
                divs.append(n/i)
            }
        }
    }
    return divs.sorted()
}

func isPractical(n: Int) -> Bool {
    // 1 and 2 are practical numbers:
    if n == 1 || n == 2 {
        return true
    }
    // Every other practical number must be divisible by 4 or 6:
    if n % 4 != 0 && n % 6 != 0 {
        return false
    }
    // Every power of 2 is a practical number:
    if n & (n-1) == 0 {
        return true
    }

    var isSumOfDivisors = Array(repeating: false, count: n)
    isSumOfDivisors[0] = true
    var last = 0 // Index of last `true` element.

    // For all divisors d of n (except n):
    for d in divisors(n).dropLast() {
        // For all i which are a sum of smaller divisors (in reverse order, so that
        // we can simply update the array):
        for i in stride(from: min(last, n-1-d), through: 0, by: -1) where isSumOfDivisors[i] {
            // Mark i + d:
            isSumOfDivisors[i + d] = true
            if i + d > last {
                last = i + d
            }
        }
    }

    // n is "practical" if isSumOfDivisors[i] == true for all i = 0...n-1:
    return !isSumOfDivisors.contains(false)
}
```

Test code:

```
let startDate = Date()
let practicalNumbers = (1...10_000).filter(isPractical)
let endDate = Date()
print(endDate.timeIntervalSince(startDate))

print(practicalNumbers)
```

On my MacBook, this computes the practical numbers up to 1,000 in 0.003 seconds, and up to 10,000 in 0.1 seconds.

Comment: That logic for summing permutations of the divisors is magic! It dropped my time to generate 1-to-1000 from 10 minutes to the under-one-second time you said.  https://github.com/WithoutHaste/RecreationalMath/blob/master/pythonGenerators/generate_practical.py

Answer (score 2):

The indentation of your code looks messy in some places. Let your IDE format the code for you. At least the `counts = divArray` line needs to be further to the right, and the closing brace at the end of that line needs to be on a line of its own.

The code should have a function called `isPractical(x)`. That function should look approximately like the following, for a very naive approach, but maybe that works already.

```
func isPractical(num:Int) -> Bool {
    var factors = getFactors(num)
    for i in 1...num {
        if (!isSumPossible(i, factors)) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

I don't understand your variable names. Imagine you would explain this program to a human. Which words would you use to describe the purpose of each of these variables? These words are the basis for good names.

- `getInteger` should be called `readInt`
- `firstNum` is unnecessary, since you can just `return unwrappedInt`
- `input` should be called `line`
- `addOne` should be called `nextCombination`
- `signArray` should not have the word `sign` in its name, since a 0 in that array means *take this number*

Instead of `if condition { numCheck = true } else { numCheck = false }`, you can simply write `numCheck = condition`.

Swift has the remainder operator `%`, which can be used like this:

```
if number % 4 == 0 {
    print("Divisible by 4")
}
```

Instead of using `pow(2, n)`, you can write `1 << n`, which has the same result for `Int`, but is simpler and faster.

All the above will not help you with the `time-limit-exceeded`, but it will make your program readable enough so that others may want to have a look at it. So when you have fixed all the above issues, feel free to post another new question.